# What is utility?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

As part of Q learning an objective is to maximize the expected utility. I know

Reading wikipedia  :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning describes expected utility in following contexts :

> It works by learning an action-value function that ultimately gives
> the expected utility of taking a given action in a given state and
> following the optimal policy thereafter.
>
> One of the strengths of Q-learning is that it is able to compare the
> expected utility of the available actions without requiring a model of
> the environment.

But does not define what utility is, what is meant by utility ?

When maximizing `utility` what exactly is being maximized ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, "utility" means functionality or usefulness. So "maximum functionality" or "maximum usefulness".

Plugging the word into Google gives you:

> the state of being useful, profitable, or beneficial.

Comment: So utility is the same as the reward in the reward function?

Answer (score 2):

In general terms, *utility* means profitable or beneficial (as @Rob posted in his response).

In Q-learning context, *utility* is closed related (they can be viewed as synonyms) with *action-value function*, as you read in Wikipedia explanation. Here, the action-value function of policy `π` is an estimation of the return (long term reward) that the agent is going to obtain if it performs the action `a` in a given state `s` and follows the policy `π`. So, when you maximizes the utility, actually you are maximizing the rewards your agent will obtain. As rewards are defined to achieve a goal, you are maximizing the "quantity" of goal achieved.

Comment: So from this explanation, reward seems to be the same as utility as well. This initially threw me off because I thought the two were different things

Comment: Both terms are related, but they are different. We can say *reward* is a (short term) quantity that indicates the goal (e.g., in chess game, to win the game). You should decide that your agent recives a positive reward when it wins. However, the *utility* is an estimation of the (long term) reward that the agent will recive in a given state-action, and following a given policy. The agent should learn the *utility*. In chess game, it should learn what movements are useful to win.